# What is the value of $e^\frac{-1}{e}$?

Tags: calculus

As the title suggests, what is the value of $e^\frac{-1}{e}$?? I never understood how things to the power of irrational numbers are calculated. The more broad question would be what is the minimum value for the function $y=x^x$, such that $x \geq 0$? I have tried taking the derivative to get $x^x(\ln(x)+1) = 0$, then simplifying to get $\ln(x)+1=0$, and $\ln(x)=-1$, so $x = \frac{1}{e}$. This simplifies to $e^\frac{-1}{e}$. What do I put for my final answer? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Would you prefer $e^{-1/e}$?

Comment: Yes, I'll edit that

Comment: Also, I would like to note that this isn't a contest question - there is not necessarily a different answer. If that is how I am supposed to write my answer, then that is very possible too.

Comment: $e^{-1/e}$ is just $e^{-1/e}$. You could write it in a couple of ways, for instance $e^{-e^{-1}}$, but there is no reason to prefer one over the other.

Comment: I don't see any point of writing anything other than $e^{-1/e}$

Comment: The only other possibility would be to use $e^{-x} = \dfrac1{e^x}$, so you could write $\dfrac1{e^{1/e}}$, but I wouldn't bother.

Comment: But how would a calculator determine the value of e^/-1/e?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the replies indicate, you should put $e^{\frac{-1}{e}}$ since there is no simpler form.

Nevertheless, you seem to seek an intuition into irrational exponents, namely $\frac{-1}{e}$.

The basic idea is that **every real number is the limit of a sequence of rational numbers**, in this case with the help of the Taylor series of $e^x$
$$\frac{-1}{e}=-e^{-1}=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}
= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n!}
=-1+\frac{1}{1!}-\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!}-\frac{1}{4!}+\cdots$$

Which follows
$$ \exp\left(\frac{-1}{e}\right)
= \exp\left(\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n!} \right)
= \prod\limits_{n=0}^\infty \exp\left( \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n!} \right)
= e^{-1}\cdot e^{\frac{1}{1!}}\cdot e^{-\frac{1}{2!}}\cdot e^{\frac{1}{3!}}\cdot e^{-\frac{1}{4!}}\cdot\dots
$$
Which translates into a product of roots of $e$ and $\frac{1}{e}$.

$$e^{\frac{-1}{e}} = e^{-1}\cdot e\cdot \sqrt{e^{-1}}\cdot \sqrt[3!]{e}\cdot
\sqrt[4!]{e^{-1}}\cdot \ldots$$

While the obtained expression might *make sense*, it is not mathematically significant.

However, one might use this expression to write a small program to compute $e^\frac{-1}{e}$ in the desired precision.

Check out [Real exponents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Real_exponents) on Wikipedia.